# Calculating statistical significance of peak over background in counting experiment

Tags: particle-physics, measurements, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

I histogrammed the invariant masses of particular events in a counting experiment. There is a specific peak which towers over the expected exponential background. How can I give the statistical significance of this peak in a similar way to how a discovery in particle physics is announced at 5-sigma? i.e. how can I say 'this peak is evidence for an x-sigma discovery'?

Comment: Relevant arxiv article: [Signal Significance in Particle Physics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/0208005.pdf)

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the $p$ value in each bin of the histogram? This would give you the local significance. This usually involves throwing a vast amount of Monte Carlo pseudo experiments or using Asympotic Formulae (http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1727) to approximate the result.

Comment: @pnfnusel that's not quite right. Local significances include all the data. But only consider a fixed e.g. mass and width of the resonance. A global significance considers the probability of such an extreme test-statistic for any of the mass/width hypotheses considered.

Comment: Are you doing a hypothesis test (a background model versus a signal model) or just a goodness-of-fit (testing background only)?

Comment: What sources of errors are there? Only statistical? Or appreciable systematic too?

Comment: Only statistical errors. Based on your explanation, I'm fairly sure I am doing a hypothesis test. Essentially I want to know the probability that the peak I can see is a physical phenomenon and not just a statistical fluctuation in the background.

Comment: @james you want to calculate the probability of obtaining a test statisitc that extreme assuming that the background only model is correct.